# I'm encountering issues docker file sharing : setting volumes

Tags: php, docker, nginx, server, virtual-machine

I have problem mounting local directory and get `File sharing has been cancelled`.

Have had checked lots of forums and still have no clue how to fix it.

OS : windows enterprice version 1909

docker cli version : 19.03.8

docker-compse version : 1.25.5

I was going to serve php website using nginx web server.

[image: error diagnose]

[image: docker-compose.yml]

[image: nginx site.conf]

Comment: For the volume you're mounting, does it exist?

Comment: yeah I'm sure it exists. @JayBlanchard

Comment: You don't sound sure. Is `./code` the full path to the volume you're trying to mount?

Comment: Why you think I'm certain?

Comment: Try using the actual full path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My problem is solved! by setting up correct file sharing directory**

First of all, I have no idea whether downloading the edge version of docker could impact on it.
But When I tried setting up right directory for file sharing in docker's setting it worked.

As my project was store at :
D:\Projects\Docker\test

I needed to set file sharing permission on docker's setting to access drive D:\

Steps :

1. Open Docker setting
2. Click on Resources Item
3. Click on file sharing tab
4. browse the directory you are working on
5. Restart docker windows